# If I use a lambda to subscribe to click event how do i dispose or unsubscribe?

Tags: c#

If I use a lambda to subscribe to click event how do I dispose or unsubscribe?

```
button1.Click += (s, e) => { MessageBox.Show("You clicked the button"); };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the lambda to a variable first; e.g.:

```
EventHandler handler = (s, e) => MessageBox.Show("You clicked the button");

// attach handler
button1.Click += handler;

// remove handler
button1.Click -= handler;
```